# No matching authentication protocol while connecting do DB with SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to Oracle database (19c) using Oracle SQL Developer (3.0.04.34) and I get below error:

`Status: Failure - Test failed: ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol`

What could be the reason - is client version too old for db version?

Comment: Are you using instant client? Which version? Anyway it's better to update your SQL Developer and then probably you will need to set `disable_oob=on` in sqlnet.ora

Comment: I agree that using such an old version of SQL Developer is a bad idea. You're two **major** releases behind. You've got the latest version of the database itself, why not upgrade the tools to match? [Download here](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html)

Comment: Version 3 released in 2010, 19c released in 2019...um, yeah upgrade (20.2)